# Execute Virtual Box Shared Folder Mount on Startup on Cent OS 7

Tags: linux, boot, virtualbox, centos, systemd

I try to execute a mount command on startup in Cent OS 7. With FSTabs it did not work, so I tried the following:

1. Creating the folder vbox-shared-folder-mount.service with the following content:

   ```
   [unit]
   Description=VboxMountSharedFolder

   [Service]
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/mount -t vboxsf Webentwicklung /home/adminuser/Webentwicklung

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
2. Called

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable vbox-shared-folder-mount.service
   ```

After a reboot, it is not mounted. When I execute:

```
sudo systemctl start vbox-shared-folder-mount.service
```

everything works until the next restart.

Can you help me?

Comment: Ummm, is the CentOS the host or the guest? If it's the host, then the guest isn't running when the host boots, right?

Comment: It`s a Cent OS 7 in a Virtual Machine on a Windows 7 host